# ModalPopupExtender "Y" property to be set using Javascript

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender, scriptmanager

I have a ModalPopupExtender.

I can access the Modalpopupextender using javascript like

```
$find('expPopup_invite')
```

There is a Property of ModalPopupExtnder called as **Y**

I want to set this property using javascript.

Example:

To show the ModalPopupExtender using javascript i can :

```
$find('expPopup_invite').show();
```

But i want to set this Y property.

ANy help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accordance with ASP.NET Ajax Naming Standards,

> Property accessors should always be prefixed with “get_” and “set_”
>   respectively

[Naming Standards](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_contribute_codingStandards_Naming.ashx)

So in this particular case you can use:

```
$find('expPopup_invite').set_Y(123);
```